# PIP only accessable in its home file

Tags: python, pip

I want to start coding with the Python-framework Flask and therefor I have to install it using PIP. I have installed PIP on my machine, but I can only use it when i run it, while I'm in `C:\Users\RulezDZN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts` where the `pip.exe` is.
Can I just install Flask anyways or how could I fix it?
Thanks :)

Comment: Add that location to your `PATH`

Comment: Also, you can install packages wherever you want. `pip install --target="desired/location", package_name`

Comment: thanks @CoryKramer , it works!

Comment: You could also set up a virtualenv specifically for this, and install flask in that environment.